# How to redirect a subdomain to a website directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a main site hosted on Heroku and a Wordpress blog hosted on Bluehost. To get to the blog, a user types in `blog.example.com` and it works. However, how would I redirect the URL so that when the user types in `blog.example.com` the URL changes to `example.com/blog`?

I added these two commands into the `.htaccess` file and the site goes into a redirect loop:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/blog/%1 [L,R=301]
```

This is what I have in the .htaccess file so far (Wordpress default):

```
     RewriteEngine on

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't, This isn't a simple htaccess issue

Unless your Blog is hosted to `example.com` as well, or you `OWN` both DNS record

`blog.example.com` is a domain pointer, and `example.com` could be pointed to another different locations.

to rewrite all your URL to another domain, it has to be hosted there or else the DNS record will never hit the wordpress to begin with.

Incase you own both, You can point dns for `blog.example.com` to the same place as `example.com` then in wordpress site setting change your wordpress site url to `example.com/blog`

**Note WORDPRESS is hosted on `example.com` domain**